# NodeJS: RequestError: No connection is specified for that request. [package: mssql-session-store]

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, web

I'm trying to store user session in **Sql Server Database**
I'm using `mssql-session-store` module for this purpose

```
const app = express();
const { sql,config } = require("./util/database");
const session = require("express-session");
const SqlStore = require("mssql-session-store")(session);

//setting option for session
var options = {
  pool:new sql.ConnectionPool(config),
  ttl: 3600
};

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "my secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new SqlStore(options),
  })
);


//create server and listen for request
app.listen(3000);
```

I'm setting the session property with this code

```
app.use('/',(req, res) => {
  const name = req.body.user;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const user = new User(name, email);
  req.session.isAuthenticate = true;
  res.redirect("/");
};)
```

With the above code I'm getting the following Error

```
RequestError: No connection is specified for that request.
    at E:\NodeApp\OnlineShop\node_modules\mssql-session-store\node_modules\mssql\lib\main.js:1492:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

I'm following the documentation of `mssql-session-store`
[mssql-session-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql-session-store)

Please Help me out here.

Comment: Can you show us where in the documentation the `pool` property is defined for `options`? It isn't checked for in the [source code](https://github.com/jwathen/mssql-session-store/blob/master/lib/index.js#L22) either.

Comment: we can use pool in place of connection, it caused no problems.
and I have tried the connection way also it was giving me this error
```
throw new Error('If defined, options.connection must be instance of mssql.Connection.'); ^ Error: If defined, options.connection must be instance of mssql.Connection.
```

Comment: Now I'm using connect-session-sequelize for saving and deleting sessions in database.and it is working fine now. but I don't get the fix for mssql-session-store and I gave up on this package and now using alternative.